# ssh from IPv4 to IPv6

Tags: ssh, ipv6, ipv4

I have been trying to reach, using ssh, an IPv6 server from a IPv4 (only) client, but am having no success. Both systems run ubuntu 12.04.

I am aware that ipv4 and ipv6 are different protocols and have different stacks, but I thought that IPv6 could still cope with this using the ffff:ffff:...:ipv4 addressing.

I have already modified the sshd configuration file to make sure that it listens to both ipv6 and ipv4 on all interfaces.

Is there any way to ssh to this ipv6 host from my ipv4 client?

Every attempt produces the following message:
*ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection timed out*

Currently, I cannot even ping the ipv6 server. But, using ipv6 ping website I know that my client is indeed up.

Comment: If your client is IPv4 only and your server is IPv6 only its not going to work.  Your best bet would for your IPv4 client to use an IPv6 gateway, like the one at [Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net/), to get an IPv6 address in order to access the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't quite work that way. They're essentially entirely separate networks at the internet layer. While there's transitional mechanisms, you'd need to explicitly set up for them.

The *right* way to do this is to set up a tunnel (or of course, native dualstack). One does not *simply* connect across from ipv4 to 6.

Comment: Any detailed info how to set a tunnel and use to connect to ipv6?